# Build Error in Angular Library after installing and using controls of igniteui-angular

Tags: angular-library, ignite-ui-angular

I have created an angular project which also has an angular library in which I need to install and use Ignite UI for angular. When I install it using the command `"npm i igniteui-angular"` and use `NgxInputGroupModule` in it, it starts giving build error given below;

```
BUILD ERROR : Template parse errors: The pipe 'titlecase' could not be found 
             ("dy-row"> <span *ngFor="let dayName of generateWeekHeader()" 
            class="igx-calendar__label">[ERROR ->] {{ dayName | titlecase }}
        </span>
    </div> "): D:/GitProjects/BASFProj/projects/ssi- 
        framework/node_modules/igniteui-angular/igniteui- 
        angular.d.ts.IgxCalendarComponent.html@38:3 The pipe 'titlecase' 
        could not be found ("Month($event)" [igxCalendarMonth]="month" 
        [index]="i" *ngFor="let month of months; index as i;"> [ERROR ->]         
        {{ formattedMonth(month) | titlecase }}
        </div>
    </div> "): D:/GitProjects/BASFProj/projects/ssi- 
               framework/node_modules/igniteui-angular/igniteui- 
               angular.d.ts.IgxCalendarComponent.html@53:3
```

any help to get rid of this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Angular do you have installed? The error says that the angular titlecase pipe cannot be found: https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly installing `igniteui-angular` and setting it up manually inside your project, perform

`ng add igniteui-angular`

The error you're getting seems like one or more of the angular packages was not installed correctly. The pipe that cannot be found belongs to `@angular/common`. Delete your `node_modules` and perform `npm install` again.